# How to revise the Scala code to let it stop the calculation?

Tags: java, scala

Given that I have the following Scala code:

```
import java.util.concurrent._

object TimeOutTask {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
    val futureTask = new FutureTask(
      new Callable[Boolean] {
        override def call(): Boolean = {
          println("calculation begins:")
          val t0 = System.nanoTime: Double
          sum(2000000000)
          val t1 = System.nanoTime: Double
          println("Elapsed time " + (t1 - t0) / 1000000000.0 + " secs")
          true
        }
      })

    try {
      executorService.submit(futureTask).get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
    catch {
      case e: TimeoutException =>
        System.out.println("Time out~~~")
        e.printStackTrace()
        executorService.shutdownNow()
    }
  }

  def sum(k: BigInt): BigInt = {
    var total: BigInt = 0
    for (i <- (1: BigInt) to k) total += i
    total
  }
}
```

I would like to keep the executing time of `sum()` below 5 second. However, I discovered that `executorService.shutdownNow()` cannot stop the executing of `sum()` when I test it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The sum method somehow needs to know that it should stop computing the sum.
Which is possible, because the executorService will try to interrupt the thread when shutting down.

The sum method could check if the thread in interrupted and if so, it should throw an InterruptedException:

```
  def sum(k: BigInt): BigInt = {
    var total: BigInt = 0
    for (i <- (1: BigInt) to k) {
      if (Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException
      total += i
    }
    total
  }
```